How to conditionally use import statement in terraform?
I have a terraform import file which imports a ACM certificate to the statefile. I have to use this file across environments. Problem is I also upload a certificate to ACM, therefore when I want to upload certificate, I don't want to execute the import block.
Import block code:
import {
  count = var.lb_certificate_arn != "" ? 1 : 0
  to    = module.acm_cert_import.aws_acm_certificate.import_cert[0]
  id    = var.lb_certificate_arn
}

Resource block code:
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "upload_cert" {
  count             = var.secret_name != "" ? 1 : 0
  private_key       = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version[count.index].secret_string)["private_key"]
  certificate_body  = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version[count.index].secret_string)["certificate_body"]
  certificate_chain = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version[count.index].secret_string)["certificate_chain"]
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "import_cert" {
  count                     = length(var.domain_name) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  domain_name               = length(var.domain_name) > 0 ? var.domain_name[0] : ""
  subject_alternative_names = length(var.domain_name) > 0 ? var.domain_name : []
}

Here you can see that I have applied condition for both the resource such that I can manage it as required.
Since I have var.lb_certificate_arn pointing to an existing loadbalancer ARN, it gets executed as an import deleting all the configuration in the load balancer with the default ones.
Error:

│ Error: Invalid expression
│
│   on acm/main.tf line 23, in resource "aws_acm_certificate" "import_cert":
│   23:   count  =  var.lb_certificate_arn != ? 1 : 0
│
│ Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

Note: Im using Terraform v1.8.1 as terraform version

As far as I know, you cannot use variables in the import block.

Also, the error you are getting is because the condition in the ternary operator is comparing to nothing, i.e, you just have the variable reference without doing any kind of comparison: var.lb_certificate_arn != ? 1 : 0.

If you need to import only selectively into some instances of your root module, I think you'll need to use the terraform import command instead of import blocks. import assumes that the same import rules apply to all instances of the module it's used in, whereas terraform import is an imperative command you can choose to use selectively only for environments that need it.

You can use for_each to achieve conditional application of import block:
locals {
  var.lb_certificate_arn != "" ? certificates = {
    "cert1": {
      "domain_name": "example.com",
      "version": 0
  } : {}
}

import {
  for_each = local.certificates
  to    = module.acm_cert_import.aws_acm_certificate.import_cert[each.key]
  id    = var.lb_certificate_arn
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "upload_cert" {
  for_each          = local.certificates
  private_key       = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version[each.value.version].secret_string)["private_key"]
  certificate_body  = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version[each.value.version].secret_string)["certificate_body"]
  certificate_chain = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version[each.value.version].secret_string)["certificate_chain"]
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "import_cert" {
  for_each                  = local.certificates
  domain_name               = each.value.domain_name
  subject_alternative_names = each.value.domain_name
}

I am not exactly sure what this particular code is doing, but I just demonstrated how to use for_each in this particular case. Hope it helps.
